# SUDO - iOS FTP - Stuck

Tags: iphone, bash, unix, sudo, su

I have a script for MobileTerminal in iOS that requires su,
is there any way I can add a command to the bash script to login as root without having to type su then the password?

Cheers,

Dec

Answer (score 1):

SUDO and system functions are disallowed in iOS, they violate sandboxing and security.

Comment: My phone is jailbroken meaning that I'm passed sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution worked for me:

1. Jaibreak
2. Install sudo from Cydia
3. Install OpenSSH from Cydia
4. SSH to your iPhone

   ```
   $ssh root@<your iphone ip>
   Password: alpine //no echo
   ```

   and run

   ```
   iPhone:~ root# visudo
   ```

   add right after

   ```
   root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
   ```

   this line (varies of what you want)

   ```
   mobile  ALL=(ALL) ALL
   ```
5. Save changes. Now you can `sudo`. For editing with `visudo` you should use controls like in `vi`
6. After all add to your script hardcoded `sudo` call like this

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo -S -p "" echo -n "" <<!
   alpine
   !
   sudo echo "This line is printed as root"
   ```

   Now explanation:

   - `-S` allows reading password from `<<!\n ... \n!` block, it should be printed on a single line
   - `-p ""` suppresses password promt, so the line `Password:` is not printed
   - `echo -n` disallows  a newline character in the end

So you can `sudo` in your script without any password promt. The only thing - in this method password is hardcoded. But you can try command line arguments like $1 (not tested, just an idea)